# In Gradle, can deprecation warnings be prevented in code autogenerated by the MapStruct annotation processor?

Tags: java, gradle, mapstruct, annotation-processing, deprecation-warning

I have a Java project built using [Gradle](https://gradle.org) using the [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org) code generator to generate mapping code.  I intentionally have deprecation warnings enabled, as I want to be made aware if I end up calling deprecated code, e.g. when upgrading library versions.

I have a MapStruct mapper interface (annotated with [`@Mapper`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mapstruct/mapstruct/1.4.2.Final/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html)) that contains a mapping method.  The mapping method & one of the [custom mapping methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods) it uses are being used by a feature which will be removed in the next major release version of the software, but which need to remain in the minor versions leading up to that point.  Therefore, I have marked these two methods as `@Deprecated` in order to communicate that they are going away, and to make sure I don't miss removing them when I remove the other deprecated code.

When I compile the code, I get two deprecation warnings in the concrete class auto-generated by MapStruct for the mapper interface: one for implementing the deprecated mapping method, and one for calling the custom mapper method.

### Goal

I'm hoping for a way to prevent these deprecation warnings from being emitted, while still keeping deprecation warnings for my own (non-autogenerated) code.

If I had hand-written the code, I would have annotated it with `@Deprecated`, which would suppress this warning.  Alternatively, there's `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` option to suppress it.  However, MapStruct currently [doesn't allow adding annotations to its generated code](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1574).

The other option that occurs to me is perhaps there's a way in Gradle to enable deprecation warnings just for generated classes (in `build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java`), but not for hand-written classes (in `src/main/java`).  I'm not seeing a drop-in way of doing this.  There's an old forum post from nine years ago [discussing the issue](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-disable-compile-warnings-for-generated-classes/7343), though I'm not sure how to apply it to the current Gradle landscape.

How can I suppress the auto-generated mapper class deprecation warnings without disabling the deprecation warnings for my non-generated code in the project?

### Example

**`build.gradle`**

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
}

compileJava {
    options.deprecation = true
}
```

**Java classes**

```java
public class Source {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

```java
public class Target {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface ExampleMapping {
    @Deprecated
    Target map(Source source);

    @Deprecated
    default String mapString(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**Build output**

```
$ ./gradlew build

> Task :compileJava
/path/to/project/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/com/example/ExampleMappingImpl.java:13: warning: [deprecation] map(Source) in ExampleMapping has been deprecated
    public Target map(Source source) {
                  ^
/path/to/project/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/com/example/ExampleMappingImpl.java:20: warning: [deprecation] mapString(String) in ExampleMapping has been deprecated
        target.setValue( mapString( source.getValue() ) );
                         ^
2 warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

**Generated code**

```java
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-07-16T22:41:15-0500",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-7.1.1.jar, environment: Java 11.0.9.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
public class ExampleMappingImpl implements ExampleMapping {

    @Override
    public Target map(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.setValue( mapString( source.getValue() ) );

        return target;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation warnings can only be turned off globally, on the compilation level. So to disable them only for the generated mapper you'd have to compile it separately. The easiest solution would be to have the model and mappers in separate modules. Then in the mapper module just disable deprecation warnings for the 'main' sourceSet of the mapper module:

```
tasks.named('compileJava', JavaCompile).configure {
    it.options.deprecation = false
}
```

As for the test compilation I guess you'd like to have the deprecation warnings there:

```
tasks.named('compileTestJava', JavaCompile).configure {
    it.options.deprecation = true
}
```

Here's an example on GitHub: https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--mapstruct-mapper-compile-warnings

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming MapStruct version 1.6.0 will automatically copy the `@Deprecated` annotation to the generated code, per issue [#2773](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2773).  This will prevent the deprecation warnings in the given example.